# Preserving a Dead Branch AS IS for a Staff

Tags: finishing, physical-protection

I found a dead branch in the woods that I want to preserve and turn into a wizard staff for a cosplay/Halloween costume. The branch was very dead when I found it, so I think it's pretty dry, and I want to keep it looking basically the same as it was when I found it. It has a lot of lichen and some moss, as well as a few large (1/4") splits in the wood. It seems sturdy despite the splits as I gave it quite the beating on the way home.

What is the best way to keep the bark and lichen preserved on the staff? The moss can be optional as I'm guessing it would lose its color in time.

*Side Note: This is my first real wood-related project so I don't have any real experience with this sort of thing.*

Answer (score 5):

> The branch was very dead when I found it, so I think it's pretty dry,

There are various levels of 'dry' for wood. Sitting exposed outdoors, especially if lying on the ground, the wood won't be quite as dry as you'd imagine (especially in its interior). When you pick up any wood from outdoors it should be expected that in the relatively dry and stable conditions indoors it will dry further. With a branch this drying will take a bit longer than with a plank of similar thickness because the bark acts as a partial moisture barrier.

As the branch dries more any existing cracks may widen and/or lengthen slightly and some new ones may form. You'll just have to roll with this as there's basically nothing you can do to prevent it with a whole branch.

As for the bark, if you're lucky the species of tree that the branch belongs to has bark that stays strongly attached over time and becoming drier won't affect it much. If you're unlucky it'll begin to flake or peel off. You'll just have to see how it goes over time.

The lichen is probably very brittle as it is and I don't think there's anything you can do to improve on this, handling will as a result flake some of it off. The moss will dry out over time and slowly lose its colour (good news is it may take many months) and as it gets drier I imagine its hold on the bark will diminish.

So probably your best course of action is try to handle the mossy and lichen-encrusted areas as little as possible.

Comment: So what should I do to preserve it? The only real idea I've had is to clean it off and put a few layers of polyurethane on it. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Sorry I thought it would be clear from what I'd written, I'm suggesting you do nothing to it. Applying matt waterbased polyurethane would be fine for the wood (this the finish often used for driftwood items, *don't* use oil-based poly unless you're OK with a noticeable change in the colour), But I don't know how it would affect the lichen and moss, the simple act of brushing the finish on may damage them more than you'd like.

Comment: Caleb: Long time ago (30 years?) I found a cool looking (dried-out) branch while hiking and preserved it by spraying it with polyurethane and that has worked-out very well. The primary difference being that it didn't have moss and lichen on it, so I don't know how they would react. Regardless, the main point is that spraying whatever finish you want on it seems less likely to disturb the things yours has attached to its surface.

Comment: @martineau You should leave this Comment under OP's post or use the @ symbol so he gets a notification, he's unlikely to see this otherwise.

Comment: Graphus: I believe the OP will be notified just because I left a comment under one of the answers to their question — at least that's how it works on stackoverflow — which is why I intentionally left the @ off the front of their user id. Maybe @Caleb can verify whether my assumption is correct (that they received notification  when I posted my original comment).

Comment: Yes I did get notified @martineau. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the woods where you found the branch aren't too far from where you live, the climate in your backyard will be *similar* to the climate in the woods.

I'd suggest storing your wizarding staff in a shady place in the backyard, lying on the ground, just like you found it. The moisture in the air and that which is wicked up from the dirt should keep the moss & lichen going strong. If the branch is thick enough, it will be years before it starts decaying enough that you'd have to worry about it crumbling or breaking.

- Storing it in a spot that receives a lot of sun will likely kill off the lichen and moss more quickly - they usually grow in the shade.
- Storing it indoors will cause it to dry far more rapidly than it will outdoors, leading to additional splitting and the death of the moss/lichen.

When you either decide to retire the staff from active use, or it does start to decay enough that you're concerned that it may start falling apart soon, that would be the time to move it indoors to protect what's left of it. Prior to doing so, take it on one last adventure to the woods to find its replacement.